# Overriding Name for QuoteDocument

Tags: attachment, pdf, quote

We create PDFs from quotes, and they get filenames on the form VX.pdf (where X increments). So customer wants to have the filenames be -.pdf. I've tried setting the ContentVersion PathOnClient to something different, but when the QuoteDocument is created when the user clicks 'save', the Name of the file is set to the same value, regardless. And the Name field of QuoteDocument is non-writable.

Is there some way around this?

Comment: QuoteDocuments get the quotename with version increments by default and there is no way to set the name. If you try to change the name it will fail,  just like Salesforce is in an existential way.